# Tossing 10 coins, what's the easiest way to see that these two events are independent?

Tags: probability

We toss 10 identical biased coins. Let $I$ and $J$ be the event that the $i$-th and $j$-th toss ($i,j\in\mathbb{N}_{[2,10]}$) are different from their predecessors, respectively. What's the easiest way to see that $I$ and $J$ are independent whenever $|i-j|>1$?

Comment: Well, one way would be to verify that $P(I \cap J) = P(I)P(J)$ by direct computation.

Comment: @AlanGuo: You are right. But I'm expecting an explanation on how to understand it more intuitively or why exactly this rule fails when $|i-j|=1$

Comment: Is $i \in \{0, 1\}$? Can you be more specific with your notation?

Comment: @AlexOlssen: $i,j\in\{2,3,...,10\}$

Comment: @AlexOlssen: $I$ and $J$ are events that those tosses are  "different from their predecessors," instead of whatever their outcomes.

Comment: I am confused by the notation. If I define $E_i = 1$ if $r_i \neq r_{i-1}$ (using Alex's notation), and $0$ otherwise, how is $E_i$ related to events $I$, $J$?

Comment: @copper.hat: $I=E_i$, $J=E_j$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $|i - j| = 1$ then one of the tosses is the predecessor of the second toss. Since the coins are biased ($p \in (0,1)$, and $p \neq \frac{1}{2})$, knowing that a coin agrees with its predecessor changes our probability of it being heads or tails.

That is $P(Heads |\text{ agrees with predecessor}) = \frac{P(Heads \text{ and agrees with predecessor})}{P(\text{agrees with predecessor})} = \frac{p^2}{p^2 + (1-p)^2} = \frac{p^2}{1 - 2p(1-p)} \neq p$ if $p \neq 0,\frac{1}{2},1$.

So, intuitively, if $p > \frac{1}{2}$, then if $I$ is true, then $i$ is most likely heads, and $i-1$ is most likely heads, and that means that $i-1$ is also more likely to agree with its predecessor (since $i-2$ is more likely heads), etc.